# When running Django tests using Travis CI, my tests are running and completing locally, but are not running (or being found) remotely

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

As per the question, I have two tests which I am running successfully on my local machine. Running "python manage.py test" in the command line produces the following output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.495s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

These tests are part of a project which is currently residing in a GitHub repository. This repository is linked to Travis CI, and as such, a travis.yml file can be found in the repository's root directory. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
language: python
install:
  - python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
before_script:
  - cd TNI_Project
script:
  - python manage.py test
```

For reference, the "TNI_Project" directory is the one which contains the "manage.py" file, and the "requirements.txt" file contains the output of `pip freeze`.

However, once the build is launched on Travis CI, the build exits with 0, but none of the tests are run. The exact output can be found below:

```
$ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
before_script
0.00s$ cd TNI_Project
0.41s$ python manage.py test
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
The command "python manage.py test" exited with 0.
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

Since the build actually completes without errors, this means that the actual problem lies in how Travis CI is unable to find my tests on the virtual machine. I can't seem to figure out why this is the case, and how to get the tests running remotely.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, could you provide the link of your github repo? I want to give it a look

Comment: Hello Could you fix your issue? I have the same.